# Trying to divide a value in Yii2 db query

Tags: yii2

I'm trying to get a value from a DB but this value is not correct so I wanted to change it (in this case divide by 100) but I can't make it to work.

```
$query->select([new \yii\db\Expression("sum(('c.api_sales_price') / 100) AS api_sales_price"),])->all();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have unnecessary quotes - `'c.api_sales_price'` is treated as value not a column name:

```
$query->select([
        new \yii\db\Expression('sum(c.api_sales_price / 100) AS api_sales_price'),
    ])
    ->all();
```